# How to display all numbers greater than 1 from List on ListView c#

Tags: c#, xamarin

I want to display all numbers greater than 1 from my list on ListView

```
foreach (var item2 in listAlert)
{
      int maxAlertt = item2.levelForecast;
      item2.levelForecast = Math.Max(maxAlertt, maxAlertt);
      lstLevel2.ItemsSource = listAlert;
}
```

`listAlert` have data with integers 1,2,3,4 I want to display only 2,3 and 4 in `lstLevel2`.

How to do that ?

Comment: item2.levelForecast = Math.Max(maxAlertt, maxAlertt);
Doesn't seem correct, the max of 2x same item.

Comment: The easiest way would be to modify the `listAlert` and remove the values that are 1. Also you should move `lstlevel2.ItemSource = listAlert;` outside the foreach loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do this with a LINQ query - you don't need a `foreach` loop

```
lstLevel2.ItemsSource = listAlert.Where(x => x.SomeProperty > SomeValue).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You're overwriting your lstLevel2.ItemsSource with each iteration. You want to split it up:

```
var list = new List<myItem>();
foreach (var item2 in listAlert)
{
    if (item2.Data > 1)
    {
        list.Add(item2);
    }
}
lstLevel2.ItemsSource = list;
```